# Can we redefine $\sin x$ as a function with a domain and codomain on $\mathbb{S}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

Let's take $f(x)= \sin x$. Then we have $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. However the codomain of $f$ is just the interval $[-1,1]$ and $f(x+ 2\pi) = f(x)$. Since $f$ is periodic, can we equivalently redefine $$f: \mathbb{S} \mapsto \tilde{\mathbb{S}}$$

where $\mathbb{S}$ is associated to $[0, 2\pi] \mbox{mod}2\pi$ and $\tilde{\mathbb{S}}$ is associated to $[-1,1]$ ? If these formulations are not equivalent, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can take the domain to be a "scaling" of $T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Take the space $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\sin$ doesn't "see" a difference of $2\pi k$ this encodes the same information.

That being said, you probably have to be careful as there are differences between the two spaces generally. For example, $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is compact, and $\mathbb{R}$ is most definitely not. But this can be an advantage (see Fourier Transforms and the Pontryagin Dual).